# Understanding the difference between the following two functions

Tags: c, shell

I am learning how to create a shell, so I need help with understanding the following code which I found in an online tutorial for creating shells.

```
/***************************************************************************//**
  @file         main.c
  @author       Stephen Brennan
  @date         Thursday,  8 January 2015
  @brief        LSH (Libstephen SHell)
*******************************************************************************/

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
  Function Declarations for builtin shell commands:
 */
int lsh_cd(char **args);
int lsh_help(char **args);
int lsh_exit(char **args);

/*
  List of builtin commands, followed by their corresponding functions.
 */
char *builtin_str[] = {
  "cd",
  "help",
  "exit"
};

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
  &lsh_cd,
  &lsh_help,
  &lsh_exit
};

int lsh_num_builtins() {
  return sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(char *);
}

/*
  Builtin function implementations.
*/

/**
   @brief Bultin command: change directory.
   @param args List of args.  args[0] is "cd".  args[1] is the directory.
   @return Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int lsh_cd(char **args)
{
  if (args[1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
  } else {
    if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Builtin command: print help.
   @param args List of args.  Not examined.
   @return Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int lsh_help(char **args)
{
  int i;
  printf("Stephen Brennan's LSH\n");
  printf("Type program names and arguments, and hit enter.\n");
  printf("The following are built in:\n");

  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    printf("  %s\n", builtin_str[i]);
  }

  printf("Use the man command for information on other programs.\n");
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Builtin command: exit.
   @param args List of args.  Not examined.
   @return Always returns 0, to terminate execution.
 */
int lsh_exit(char **args)
{
  return 0;
}

/**
  @brief Launch a program and wait for it to terminate.
  @param args Null terminated list of arguments (including program).
  @return Always returns 1, to continue execution.
 */
int lsh_launch(char **args)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (pid < 0) {
    // Error forking
    perror("lsh");
  } else {
    // Parent process
    do {
      waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
  }

  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Execute shell built-in or launch program.
   @param args Null terminated list of arguments.
   @return 1 if the shell should continue running, 0 if it should terminate
 */
int lsh_execute(char **args)
{
  int i;

  if (args[0] == NULL) {
    // An empty command was entered.
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
      return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
    }
  }

  return lsh_launch(args);
}

#define LSH_RL_BUFSIZE 1024
/**
   @brief Read a line of input from stdin.
   @return The line from stdin.
 */
char *lsh_read_line(void)
{
  int bufsize = LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
  int position = 0;
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);
  int c;

  if (!buffer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (1) {
    // Read a character
    c = getchar();

    // If we hit EOF, replace it with a null character and return.
    if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
      buffer[position] = '\0';
      return buffer;
    } else {
      buffer[position] = c;
    }
    position++;

    // If we have exceeded the buffer, reallocate.
    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
      buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
      if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }
}

#define LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define LSH_TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
/**
   @brief Split a line into tokens (very naively).
   @param line The line.
   @return Null-terminated array of tokens.
 */
char **lsh_split_line(char *line)
{
  int bufsize = LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
  char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
  char *token, **tokens_backup;

  if (!tokens) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  token = strtok(line, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE;
      tokens_backup = tokens;
      tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!tokens) {
        free(tokens_backup);
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  }
  tokens[position] = NULL;
  return tokens;
}

/**
   @brief Loop getting input and executing it.
 */
void lsh_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
    printf("> ");
    line = lsh_read_line();
    args = lsh_split_line(line);
    status = lsh_execute(args);

    free(line);
    free(args);
  } while (status);
}

/**
   @brief Main entry point.
   @param argc Argument count.
   @param argv Argument vector.
   @return status code
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Load config files, if any.

  // Run command loop.
  lsh_loop();

  // Perform any shutdown/cleanup.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between builtin functions and just directly using execvp for everything we need. execvp includes all the builtin functions that we make, so why should we bother?

Comment: `execvp` cannot directly run shell built-in functions.

Comment: @kaylum... so when we issue a command that is not a built in function such as ls, why does it work?. Does it work because execvp is the one who issues the ls program somehow?

Comment: One uses `fork()` to create a clone of itself and then uses `execvp()` in the child to replace the clone with the chosen program (e.g. `ls`).  The built-in code doesn't do the `fork()` and the action executes directly in the shell.  If you think about it, `exit` and `cd` pretty much have to be built-in to be useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but even if we don't have built in functions, cd would be passed to execvp and executes properly. The only difference I see is that builtin functions run within the same process when they are invoked and non-built functions require newly created processes to be run. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, it depends on your definition of '`cd` executes properly'.  The child process (shell) does change directory, but the parent process does not.  Similarly, with `exit`, the child would exit but the parent process would not.

Comment: I am still confused. Why is important that the parent process changes directory as well in the first case?. What's your definition of useful?

Comment: My definition of 'useful' for the `cd` command is that after it executes, the current directory for the shell is where I specified on executing the `cd` command. For example, if I'm in `$HOME` and I type `cd ./soq/src/so-4338-2945`, I expect the current directory in the shell (not the transient child process) to be `$HOME/soq/src/so-4338-2945`. However, if only the child process executes `cd`, the current directory of the parent process is unaffected by the change. In general, on Unix, a child process cannot affect the parent process unless it goes through extreme measures (runs a debugger).

Comment: ummmm, now I am understanding. In the lsh_execute function, I got rid of the for loop to see if every command still works. So basically I am just using lsh_launch(args). I tried to execute cd .. and it doesn't work. It says no such file or directory. Can u explain why this behavior occurs?

Comment: As mentioned by Jonathan Leffler, `cd` must be a built-in command. Thus, it is probably in every shell (e.g. `bash`, `csh`, `ksh`, `tcsh`, etc.) Out of curiosity, I did a `which cd` in the `bash` of my cygwin and got `which: no cd in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...)`. If you try to start a program using `lsh_execute()` (with disabled built-ins) what actually means to do `fork()`/`exec()` for `cd` this will fail. `exec()` cannot find any program named `cd`. That's why "No such file or directory". (It does not (cannot) consider built-in commands of a shell which might be any parent process.)